# Doctrine Entities on the fly

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, doctrine

I worked with Rails before, models in Rails doesn't contain any field definitions (except relations), Rails get it from database.

Using Doctrine 2 I need to create entity class and describe fields in it, write accessors, etc.

I'm new to Doctrine, can I do entities the same way I did in Rails?

Answer (score 1):

No, not as far as I know. And to me it seems like bad practice (like so much else in Rails it's good for prototyping but bad in all other aspects). You can however create your database first and then reverse engineer most of it into a model configuration for doctrine; see http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/tools.html#reverse-engineering

The way doctrine works, in terms that it actually has the models and their fields in configuration and/or code is good for 2 reasons.

One can see from the code what data you have and how to use it and even generate documentation from it. Readability is in my opinion one of the most important aspects in long living projects.

It's also good for performance. Always, but especially in better optimized languages and also more and more in newer versions of PHP.

Comment: > You can however create your database first and then reverse engineer most of it into a model configuration for doctrine < So I can reverse it on build and then extend this reversed version?

Comment: Yes you could do that. I wouldn't recommend it as not everything can properly be reversed engineered and any patches to the configuration you would need to make manually each time (or extend dotrines functionality). I don't see why you wouldn't take the 2 hours it takes to learn how to write a yaml or docblocks for the DB. For relations it often saves an awful lot of time compared to creating the constraints and tables straight in your DB.